# I've never seen this text encryption before, could anyone tell me?

Tags: text, encryption

Look at this encryption: -... . ...- . .-. -..-. .--. --- - . - --. ..- .-.. .-.. have you ever seen it before? I've tried several encryptions but I can't find this one. It would be nice if anyone could tell me which encryption it is.

Comment: It looks like [morse code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code)

Comment: Seriously, you've never seen morse code before? It's... pretty famous.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking to identify an encryption scheme, not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be Morse Code. Each letter is represented by a combination of dots and dashes.

Comment: Yeah. It does look like morse code.

Comment: Thank you very much.. Why didn't I think of that..

Comment: @mathias No problem! Glad I could help you out.